# Node.js and angular user authorization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

How can i block request in node.js for HTML files when user was not authorized. I have html tree something like this:

```
app.use('/templates', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'templates')));
```

- index.html (for all)
- panel.html (only for authorized)
- settings.html (only for authorized)

Is any good and clearcode solutions for block this content ?? I think about something like this:

```
router.get('/templates/panel.html', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session && req.session.user) {
   // return content
  } else {
    // block content or send error.html
  }
});
```

My ng-router config:

```
  when('/panel', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/panel.html',
    controller: 'panelController',
    // maybe controls authorize here to
  }).
```

But what will happen when we use $templateCache?

Comment: `$templateCache` is totally on UI side  if you want to use it then send any error code if you find that code then redirect to some other from ng-router

Comment: else you can redirect from node server then also template Cache will work

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you don't want other users to access some information, not to hide html templates.*

Probably the best way would be to compile all your templates to $templateCache. Then inside your routing you could use the `resolve` property [read here that](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider):

> An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the
>   controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will
>   wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the
>   controller is instantiated. **If all the promises are resolved**
>   **successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and**
>   **$routeChangeSuccess event is fired. If any of the promises are**
>   **rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired**. For easier access to
>   the resolved dependencies from the template, the resolve map will be
>   available on the scope of the route, under $resolve (by default) or a
>   custom name specified by the resolveAs property (see below). This can
>   be particularly useful, when working with components as route
>   templates.

this would allow you to do requests to server side where you will check for user privileges to open desired page.

Plus you would like to have some kind of authorization check on the server side when serving information for those pages-that-need-special-privileges.

It is also good idea to namespace your resources so authorization can be done easier and in 1 place.